# Android: Setting Background Image for RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have downloaded an image at runtime. Now I want to set it as a background for `RelativeLayout`. Does it possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out the [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), or maybe [createFromPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath(java.lang.String)) in the Drawable class.

```
   RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.rLayout);
   Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
   Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage); //new Image that was added to the res folder

    rLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```

Comment: Yeah, you could use the createFromPath to create a Drawable object from the path where your newly downloaded image will resides in

Answer (score 5):

Instead use:

```
View lay = (View) findViewById(R.id.rLayout);
lay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newImage);
```

This works because `R.drawable.newImage` refers to an integer. So you could do:

```
int pic = R.drawable.newImage;
lay.setBackgroundResource(pic);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Xamarin.Android (Cross Platform) -

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout (this);
```

OR

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)FindViewById (Resource.Id.relativeLayout);
```

AND

```
relativeLayout.SetBackgroundDrawable (Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.imageName));
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the onCreate function:**

```
RelativeLayout baseLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.the_layout_id);

Drawable drawable = loadImageFromAsset();

if(drawable != null){
    baseLayout.setBackground(drawable);
    Log.d("TheActivity", "Setting the background");
}
```

**The image loading method:**

```
public Drawable loadImageFromAsset() {

    Drawable drawable;

    // load image
    try {

        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("images/test.9.png");

        //Note: Images can be in hierarical 

        // load image as Drawable
        drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        Log.d("LoadingImage", "Error reading the image");
        return null;
    }

    return drawable;
}
```

**The open method:**

```
> public final InputStream open (String fileName, int accessMode)
> 
> Added in API level 1 Open an asset using an explicit access mode,
> returning an InputStream to read its contents. This provides access to
> files that have been bundled with an application as assets -- that is,
> files placed in to the "assets" directory.
> 
> fileName --- The name of the asset to open. This name can be hierarchical.
> 
> accessMode --- Desired access mode for retrieving the data.
> 
> Throws IOException
```